# Error from Gracenote EyeQ Web API

Tags: gracenote

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Gracenote web API for EyeQ. What I want is to get TV listings for a danish provider, but for now I'm just trying to make anything work. As far as I can understand I have to use the "TVCHANNEL_LOOKUP" and for that I need the correct DVB Triplet. For now I've found a triplet for a dutch provider, I think and I'm just using that for test purposes. But when ever I make the following call:

```
<QUERIES>
  <AUTH>
    <CLIENT>xxxxx</CLIENT>
    <USER>xxxxxx</USER>
  </AUTH>
  <LANG>ger</LANG>
  <QUERY CMD="TVCHANNEL_LOOKUP">
    <MODE>DVBIDS</MODE>
    <DVBIDS>
      <ONID>500</ONID>
      <TSID>16<TSID>
      <SID>16003</SID>
     </DVBIDS>
   </QUERY>
 </QUERIES>
```

I get the following response:

```
<RESPONSES>
  <MESSAGE>Could not parse query: String could not be parsed as XML</MESSAGE>
  <RESPONSE STATUS="ERROR" />
</RESPONSES>
```

I'm just using a rest plugin for chrome to test

Is there any way I can get the correct dvb triplet for the danish providers?

Kind regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a "**/**" in the ending TSID tag.

```
<TSID>16<TSID>
```

Should be

```
<TSID>16</TSID>
```

That should get you the right response from API.